# How to change values in a numpy array with a given probability and based on a distribution?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, random, vectorization

I have a numpy array,

```
a = np.zeros((5,2))

a = array([[0., 0.],
           [0., 0.],
           [0., 0.],
           [0., 0.],
           [0., 0.]])
```

**Aim:**  Each value should have a probability of changing, p = 0.05, and the value it changes to is given by a sample from a normal distribution with mean = 1, st.dev = 0.2

So far, I have tried following [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11586936/numpy-change-elements-of-an-array-with-a-given-probability):

```
a[np.random.rand(*a.shape) < 0.05] = rng.normal(loc=1,scale=0.2)
```

This does change values randomly with p = 0.05 ,but all values are the same, which is not ideal.

So, how does one go about making sure that each sampled value is independent(without using for loop)?

Comment: Just use np.random.seed(1), this will should be enough to get different values.

Comment: @Gray_Rhino That doesn't do anything to address his issue.

Comment: You have to use a `for` loop.  The problem is you don't know how many numbers you'll need until the left side of the = is evaluated, and by then it's too late.

Comment: @Gray_Rhino, that would not work, I think the issue lies in the "rng.normal(loc=1,scale=0.2)". it gets a single output and sets it for all changing indices rather than sampling independently for every index

Comment: @TimRoberts  `for` loop seems the only way then

Comment: @QuoMon Yes, I misunderstood the issue. As other have mentioned you would have to use a loop or some mapping to apply it to all elements in array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from scipy import stats

a = np.zeros((5,2))

a[:] = np.where(np.random.rand(*a.shape) < 0.05,
                stats.norm.rvs(loc=1,scale=0.2, size = a.shape),
                a)
```